# npm install -g truffle install visual studiosVsCode

Tags: python, node.js, bash, npm-install, truffle

I'm trying to follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzZEx0lumr0) and I think I'm doing something wrong, this is what is appearing in my terminal:
[image: this is what is appearing in my terminal].

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzZEx0lumr0 
im trying to follow this video and i think im doing something wrong this what it seem to appear in my terminal

Comment: hopingg someone can help me